# modify models instances and sent to another model in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have 2 models in django
Model A and Model B
in model A  exist 2 fields

```
start_hour = models.TimeField()
end_hour = models.TimeField()
```

and I want to send this instance to a function and return a list with a slot time of 1 hour.
for an example:

start_hour = '10:00'
end_hour = '15:00'

output :
[
( '10:00 – 11:00'),
( '11:12 – 12:00'),
( '12:00 – 13:00'),
( '13:00 – 14:00'),
( '14:00 – 15:00'),
]

**i wrote function and works well**

my question is :
i want in model B show list of time slot to select
not show start time and end time

`Model_A = models.ForeignKey(Model_A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

I wrote this code, but it shows the start time and end time!

Comment: Can you update the question with both your models?